# Undefined is not a fuction (evaluating '(0, _reactRedux.Connect)(mapStateToProps, {userOpenedApp:_actions.userOpenedApp})')

Tags: react-redux

[snapshot of the actioncreator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4x3r.png)
[Screenshot of the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6WSC.png)

I tried implementing redux for the first time.
I have no idea whats causing this error.
[snapshot of app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YkYI.png)

Comment: Please, add some your code or describe what you have done so far.

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to return jsx from self created helper method 'renderApp' which was trying to access app level state but the method was not inside Provider tag.
So when i noticed i created a brand new component and nested inside provider tag and applied the same thing inside the new component[screenshot of the new app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBkPr.png)[screenshot of the brand new component MovieList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqjoB.png)